# NavigationController on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I m working on iPad for the first time & I noticed that I m not able to use a UINavigationController on iPad as I have used so far on iPhone.

This is what I m trying to do.

- Use a UINavigationBarController in AppDelegate
- creating object of it and connecting it.
- create UIViewController class + XIB
- Set this XIB as navigation's root view

For iPhone it used to work but in case of iPad its not working. My ViewDidLoad method of my viewController is not getting called.

Any suggestion What should I do.

**EDIT :**

in .m
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Thanks,
Jitesh

Comment: post your code appDelegate code

Comment: It should work just the same. You probably made a mistake. So, if you want us to be able to help, provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller should work the same in iPad as iPhone - check that you've set your outlets in your nib file properly - also remember if you are using a nib name different to the view controller name (e.g. with an iPad suffix to differentiate from your iPhone nib for that VC) you need to pass the nib name on the init for the view controller.

(i.e. use)
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle

check that nib names and outlets in your main nib are all set up properly.